# How to Fix scroll issue in chat box

Tags: jquery

I had written a jquery code to auto refresh the messages in the chat box. But when I try to read old messages by scrolling up in the chat box, it doesn't allow since the chat division gets refresh for every 1 sec and get back to the fresh messages

```
 $(document).ready(function(){        
   setInterval(function(){ $('#messagesBody').load("get-messages.php? 
     employee_id="+employee_id);
     $("#messagesBody").scrollTop($("#messagesBody")[0].scrollHeight);
   }, 1000);
 });
```

i want to read the old messages in the chat box.

Answer (score 0):

FINAL EDIT:

I had a bit of time and got this snippet together. What I got wrong in my initial answer is that with the comparison between messagesBody scrollTop and scrollHeight, you also have to subtract the height of the messagesBody div, so the comparison is:

```
if ($('#messagesBody')[0].scrollTop < $("#messagesBody")[0].scrollHeight - $('#messagesBody').eq(0).height() - 50).
```

With this snippet you'll see that autoscrolling is disabled if you scroll 50 px up in the messagesBox.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){    

   var autoScroll = true;
   
   $("#messagesBody").eq(0).scroll(function() {
       if ($('#messagesBody')[0].scrollTop < $("#messagesBody")[0].scrollHeight - $('#messagesBody').eq(0).height() - 50) autoScroll = false;
       else autoScroll = true;
       
       $("#autoScrollDiv").html((autoScroll ? "true" : "false"));
   });

   setInterval(function(){
   
   $('#messagesBody').append('<p>Some more text</p><p>Some other text because why not?</p>');
   
     if (autoScroll) {
          $("#messagesBody").scrollTop($("#messagesBody")[0].scrollHeight);
       }
     }, 1000);
 });
```

```css
p {
background-color: white;
animation-name: fadeIn;
animation-duration: 2s;
animation-iteration-count:1;
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
from {background-color: #fff9d6;}
to {background-color: white;}
}

#messagesBody {
height:200px;
overflow:auto;
border:1px solid #111111;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="messagesBody">
  <p>hello</p>
  <p>hello</p>
  <p>hello</p>
  <p>hello</p>
  <p>hello</p>
  <p>hello</p>
  <p>hello</p>
  <p>hello</p>
  <p>hello</p>
  <p>hello</p>
</div>
<div id="autoScrollDiv">true</div>
```

--- OLD ANSWER BELOW ---

Several options here. I would recommend listening to a scroll event on messagesBody and only allowing auto-scrolling if the user has scrolled to the bottom (or near bottom) of the chat div. Something like:

(EDIT: autoScroll was being assigned to the wrong value)

```
//a boolean that decides whether auto scroll happens. With 50 px leeway
var autoScroll = true;
//listen for scroll event on messagesBody
$("#messagesBody).scroll(function() {
    if ( $("#messagesBody)[0].scrollTop >= $("#messagesBody")[0].scrollHeight - 50 ) autoScroll = true;
    else autoScroll = false;
});

//Elsewhere, in the code you've provided
if (autoScroll) $("#messagesBody").scrollTop($("#messagesBody")[0].scrollHeight);
```

The idea of the line:

```
if ( $("#messagesBody)[0].scrollTop >= $("#messagesBody")[0].scrollHeight - 50 )
```

Is to check if the div has been scrolled more than 50px from the bottom. If it's still 50px from bottom, then autoScroll is on, if not, it is turned off.

Comment: thank you for your response, I tried your code but its not working for me. Kindly let me know what this $("#messagesBody")[0].scrollHeight - 50 ) will actually do

Comment: Oops, I made a mistake - the autoscroll values should be swapped in my original answer. I've edited the code. I've also added my thinking afterwards

Comment: i used your code like this in my script. <script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){        
setInterval(function(){ $('#messagesBody').load("get-messages.php?employee_id="+employee_id);
$("#messagesBody").scroll(function() {
    if ( $("#messagesBody")[0].scrollTop >= $("#messagesBody")[0].scrollHeight - 50 ) autoScroll = true;
    else autoScroll = false;
});
}, 100);

});
        
</script>   still its not working, any idea

Comment: i used your code like this in my script.

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){        
setInterval(function(){ $('#messagesBody').load("get-messages.php?employee_id="+employee_id);
$("#messagesBody").scroll(function() {
    if ( $("#messagesBody")[0].scrollTop >= $("#messagesBody")[0].scrollHeight - 50 ) autoScroll = true;
    else autoScroll = false;
});
}, 100);
});       
</script>

still its not working, any idea

Comment: Heya! The scroll function, and the autoscroll Boolean declaration, should be outside the set interval function

Comment: even i tried that also, still its not working form me. what can i do now i got struct in this from last 2 weeks. @ Michael Beeson, kindly look into this please, thank you

Comment: I've edited the answer with a snippet that shows a working example

Answer (score 0):

Can use a logic like this, if user trying to scroll to top to read old messages, so we can disable `scroll down` action, if user scroll down again, re-enable `action`:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var action = true // defaul value
  setInterval(function() {

    /*$('#messagesBody').load("get-messages.php? 
    employee_id="+employee_id);*/

    if (action === true) { // if scroll is down, do this
      $("#messagesBody").scrollTop($("#messagesBody")[0].scrollHeight);
    }

    console.log(action);
  }, 1000);


  $("#messagesBody").scroll(function() {
    var height = $(this).height();

    if ($(this).scrollTop() < height) { // if user scrolled to top
      action = false; // disable your action
    } else {
      action = true; // else, re enable your aciton
    }
  });

});
```

```css
#messagesBody {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: gainsboro;
  overflow: auto;
}

p {
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="messagesBody">
  <p>hello</p>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you for you response,  But problem the scroll bar is goes down automatically when new message arrive. I want to stop that when scroll bar moves up or down

Comment: @Saif `when new message arrive` How those arrive? and how those force scroll to down?

Comment: i run your code in code snippet, you can see when messages gets arrived like true true true in your case, the scrollbar doesnt allow us to move top.

Comment: @Saif When you scroll to top it should return `false`.. and it won't back down until you bring it down again.